# How to add edittext into checkbox?

Tags: android, checkbox, android-edittext

I have code some feature which I want to add edittext into a checkbox. I dont know how to add edittext into checkbox. This my code to draw checkbox dynamicly.

```
                for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(OrderActivity.this);
                    EditText et = new EditText(OrderActivity.this);
                    cb.setText(obj.getString("color") + "  | PO : " + obj.getString("po") + "  | SO : " + obj.getString("so") + " | Available : " + obj.getString("dozen"));
                    cb.setId(i+10);
                    cb.setWidth(150);
                    ll.addView(cb);
                }
```

And this is the capture after checkbox finish drawing

[image]

Thank you very much and I hope someone to helping me.